# How to look for a file with a particular extension in the entire directory and then copy to another server

Tags: python, xml, linux, shell, unix

I am trying to copy files with a particular extension. Let's say `3gp`.

For example, let's say the file annc1.xml is having g711u.3gp file name.

I need to look into the entire directory for `3gp` file names available and then copy them to a server using sftp.

```
[root@DVRTPG009 regression]# cat annc1.xml | grep 3gp
                    <audio uri="http://10.211.0.159/mxml_clips/10_SecondClip_amr.3gp"/>
            <send target="source" event="app.10_SecondClip_amr.3gp" namelist="play.amt play.end"/>
```

Comment: [root@DVRTPG009 regression]# cat annc1.xml | grep 3gp
                <audio uri="file://mnt/10.211.0.159/mxml_clips/amr7_5_off.3gp"/>
                <send target="source" event="app.nfs_amr_3gp"  namelist="play.amt play.end"/>
                        <audio uri="http://10.211.0.159/mxml_clips/10_SecondClip_amr.3gp"/>
                <send target="source" event="app.10_SecondClip_amr.3gp" namelist="play.amt play.end"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /location/of/directory -name '*.3gp' -exec scp {} username@remoteip:/remote/location/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a python script to do that for you.
I used python paramiko, scp, look for a clean documentation
on how to use them.

```
pip install scp
easy_install paramiko
```

Test on my pc(Ubuntu 16.04) 64bit. You need to make little changes, servername, username, password, and remote directory in which you want files to be uploaded to.

```
import os
import sys
import glob 
import fnmatch 
import paramiko # for ssh may need to be installed.
from scp import SCPClient
import time 

# This may work on both linux and window or mac.
DEFAULT_DIR=os.path.expanduser("~")

server="192.168.0.100"
port=22
user="s8software"
password="!your-password.com!" # may not bee needed when we use public key something.pem
SFTP_REMOTE_PATH="/home/s8software/Documents/"

def search_directory_for_files(dirname, extension="*.py"):
    """
    Search an entire directory for particular files
    denoted with extension. and copy them to a remote server.
    @param: dirname--> The directory contains files we want to copy.
    @param: extension--> The files with a particular extension we want to copy.

    """
    if ( not dirname):
        raise AttributeError("We need at least a source directory!")

    for root, direname, filenames in os.walk(dirname):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
            yield {"fullpath":os.path.join(root, filename), "filename":filename}  

def open_scp_connection(server, port, user, password):
    """
    Function returns a well established connection to the
    server we want to transfer files to.
    """
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()

        # Note the public key here don't.
        # TODO. See how you can either pass the username and password.

        pkey = "/home/s8software/Working/Keys/KeParis/TestInstance.pem"
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        # NOTE: if you use the public_key then uncomment this line and comment
        # the one using the password.
        #client.connect(server, port, user, key_filename=pkey)

        client.connect(server, port, user, password=password)

        return client

    except:
        raise

def get_scpclient_connection(ssh_object):
    try:
        return SCPClient(ssh_object.get_transport())
    except:
        raise

def _send_remote_recursive(scp_client, file_full_path, filename):
    """
    Given a  file send them to the remote server.
    """
    try:
        print time.asctime(), 'Uploading....', filename
        return_status = scp_client.put(file_full_path, remote_path=os.path.join(SFTP_REMOTE_PATH, filename))        
    except:
        raise
    else:
        return return_status

if __name__=="__main__":
    # First open the connection using the port of the server
    endpoint_connection = open_scp_connection(server, port, user, password)
    scp_connection = get_scpclient_connection(endpoint_connection)

    # Recursely get everything we need and send to remove server.
    for f in search_directory_for_files(DEFAULT_DIR):
        source_path = f.get("fullpath")
        filename = f.get("filename")

        # Send the files to the remote server.
        _send_remote_recursive(scp_connection, source_path, filename)
```

A little modifiction though my be needed.